# NSData.bytes giving back different byte array

Tags: java, objective-c, arrays, nsdata

Basically I'm using NSData to convert my NSString to bytes or byte array.

In java "4" is represented as 52 as byte but in NSData it is 34

e.g.

```
NSString *sampleString = @"474";
NSData *data = [sampleString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

The produced result is

```
<34003700 34... >
```

Hence we are expecting

```
<52005500  52... >
```

Any idea why it is different from objective-c?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NSData object is shown as hexadecimal bytes. Hex 34 is equal to decimal 52. So the result *is* correct.